# SpecFlow + Selenium-WebDriver: Sharing a WebDriver Across Steps?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, bdd, specflow

Say I have a scenario that uses steps that are contained in two different classes. Is there a way for both of them to have a handle to the same `IWebDriver` instance without going through `ScenarioContext.Current["webdriverVariableName"]`?

That's so ugly. Is there a cleaner way?

I was going to make a class with a `public static IWebDriver` property that gets assigned at the start of every scenario, so that all my steps could refer to it, but I don't think that will work when I start to run them in parallel, as each scenario would overwrite the global driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specflow offers a Dependency Injection mecanism, so you could get your web driver instance injected in your steps.

See https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection

See the "Avanced options" section.

Answer (score 4):

I have just started using Specflow but this appears to work;

1. Create a class which takes IObjectContainer as a constructor and has a BeforScenario method to create the WebDriver instance;

   ```
   [Binding]
   public class WebDriverSupport
   {
       private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

       public WebDriverSupport(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
       {
           _objectContainer = objectContainer;
       }

       [BeforeScenario]
       public void InitializeWebDriver()
       {
           var webDriver = DriverFactory.CreateDriver();
           _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<RemoteWebDriver>(webDriver);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create your step classes with a constructor which take RemoteWebDriver;

   ```
   [Binding]
   public class POCSteps
   {
       private readonly IdlWebDriver _driver;

       public POCSteps(IdlWebDriver driver)
       {
           _driver = driver;
       }
   }
   ```

Your steps steps will now have access to a fully instantiated WebDriver object

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure i understand how this works. Where does objectContainer get assigned? wouldn't it be null unless the class is inherited?

Comment: Hi, I haven't worked on this in over 5 years so really don't remember. Apologies.  I assume that the execution of a specflow test handles the creation?

Answer (score 0):

My tests, which are currently working fine running multithreaded webdriver instances, are using a base step definitions class to hold the driver instance. All step definitions inherit from this, so the driver is available to all steps..

```
namespace Project.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class BaseStepDefinitions
    {
        private const string CurrentPageKey = "Current.Page";
        public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

        protected LogonPageModel LogonPage
        {
            get { return (LogonPageModel)ScenarioContext.Current[CurrentPageKey]; }
            set { ScenarioContext.Current[CurrentPageKey] = value; }
        }

        protected RegisterPageModel RegisterPage
        {
            get { return (RegisterPageModel)ScenarioContext.Current[CurrentPageKey]; }
            set { ScenarioContext.Current[CurrentPageKey] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

//////////////

```
namespace SpecDriver.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class LoginSteps : BaseStepDefinitions
    {
        [Given(@"I navigate to the homepage")]
        public void GivenINavigateToTheHomepage()
        {
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(SettingsManager.BaseUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new separated class with a static property that returns driver:

```
static class DriverProvider
{
    private static IWebDriver _driver;
    public static IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            if (_driver == null)
            {
                _driver = new ChromeDriver();
                _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
                _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
            return _driver;
        }
    }

}
```

Each time you will need to do something with driver, just call it in a such way:

```
SomeMethod(DriverProvider.Driver);
//
IWebelement e = DriverProvider.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("you_XPath"));
e.Click();
// etc etc etc
```